# Questions About Web Script Controller Class, Spring, AMP, and Compiling

Tags: java, compilation, controller, alfresco, cas

So I have recently been trying to integrate CAS and Alfresco on an Oracle Linux 6 virtual machine, but I haven't had much luck. So I have been going through a number of tutorials, and am currently trying to complete [THIS](http://ecmstuff.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/configuring-alfresco-for-sso-with-cas.html) one. However, under the section titled "Configuring CAS SSO for Alfresco Explorer ", I am completely lost on steps 3-5.

---

3) Make sure the URLs in the org.mycompany.cms.authentication.LoginCas Web Script controller class are correct:

```
public class LoginCas extends DeclarativeWebScript 
{
   private final static String CAS_WEBAPP_URL = "https://localhost:8443/cas-server-webapp-3.4.6";
   private final static String ALFRESCO_WEBAPP_URL = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco";
```

4) Configure the LoginCas web script controller in a Spring context file:

The declarative web script needs to be loaded and setup from a Spring bean configuration. If you are creating a new AMP file for this then add the following Spring bean configuration to the module-context.xml:

```
<bean id="webscript.org.mycompany.authentication.logincas.get" class="org.mycompany.cms.authentication.LoginCas" parent="webscript">
   <property name="authenticationService" ref="authenticationService" />
   <property name="authenticationComponent" ref="authenticationComponent" />
</bean>
```

5) Lookup how to setup an AMP build project and use it to package together the web script controller, authentication filter, CAS library, and Spring context file

The following two classes from the alfresco_war package source code need to be compiled against the Alfresco 3.4 SDK and CAS library:

```
org.mycompany.cms.authentication.LoginCas
org.mycompany.cms.authentication.CasAuthenticationFilter
```

To compile these classes you need the CAS Client library (e.g. cas-client-core-3.1.12.jar), and it need to be packaged in the AMP as well.

---

I guess starting from step 3 my question would be, where do I locate this "Web Script controller class"? Do I need an IDE installed on my virtual machine to do this/manipulate it?

I have no clue what step 4 means. Could someone try to explain this in a more simplified manner? (I have zero experience working with Spring or AMP btw)

And for step 5, while this might sound like a newbie question, what does "The following two classes from the alfresco_war package source code need to be compiled against the Alfresco 3.4 SDK and CAS library" mean exactly? I under the basic idea of what compiling is, but what does it mean to "be compiled against" and how do I go about doing that?

Thank you for any help that is offered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are learning to configure CAS while getting a crash course in Alfresco Java backed web scripts. At this point it would serve you well to run through a tutorial on extending Alfresco via the Web Script Framework. There are many resources on this subject, here are a couple.

[Alfresco Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts)

[Official Documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/ws-architecture.html)

[Jeff Potts' Intro Whitepaper](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-webscripts/web-script-article.pdf)

Now then, to answer your questions:

3.) The 'Controller Class' refers to the logic that will run when the web script is called. Since this is a java-backed web script that logic will run in a Java Class(.java) rather than the standard JavaScript(.js) file. Of course you do not **need** an IDE here, but it would be handy to create an eclipse project where you could import the Alfresco SDK, required jars for CAS, and the components of your web script into a single location (also, using ant will make building and compiling much simpler).

EDIT: To answer the 'Where' question, your controller script is [LoginCas.java](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B1JEhRIvGU2gMzI2MzAyODktZWMwZi00MTYxLTk1ZjQtMjBlNGQyZDU1Y2Qx&hl=no).

4.) In order for Alfresco to recognize your custom code you need to give Spring some information. During bootstrap, Alfresco uses Spring to load your class based on how that class is defined in a -context.xml file. The [Alfresco Module Package](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/AMP_Files) (AMP) is simply a method of storing your custom code in a neat little package for deployment. The web script framework relies heavily on Spring, so if you plan on doing a good deal of Alfresco customization I would recommend [brushing up on this technology as well.](http://www.springsource.org/tutorials)

5.) Remember what I said for question 3 about an eclipse project to house all of the necessary components? Step 5 is telling you to compile your controller class against the 3.4 SDK and the CAS jars, meaning if you were doing this at command line you would run javac while passing all of the libraries from both the Alfresco SDK and your CAS components as library arguments for that call. Ultimate goal here, obtain a compiled .class file from your .java controller. This is much easier to handle with an ANT script.

If you download the [Alfresco SDK](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_SDK) and import it into eclipse you can see some examples of how to extend Alfresco. This would be a good second step after running through some of the documentation. Hope this helps, best of luck!

Comment: Hi Stan! Thank you so much for responding to this, I was worried no one would have a clue as to what I was talking about lol. Okay, so far I get that the controller script is the LoginCas.java I found in the files I downloaded from the blog. Thus following the instructions in the blog, I modified the URLS as necessary in that script (done step 3, I believe). Moving on and looking at some of the documentation you gave me, while the steps become a little more clear, I am still slightly confused by the given documentation.